How do i turn off python suggestions in VSCode?
I just want to turn this off its doing my head in. VSCode with Pylance. Is it coming from Pylance? The most annoying feature imaginable . Can't find where it would be in settings
Pylance Type Checking Mode is apparently off
any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks


Under Extensions->Pylance->Features->Settings
Search for: python.analysis.inlayHints and disable all of them. Should do the trick.

thank you! They are all disabled :D i'm so confused

found it - general Text Editor settings - Editor › Parameter Hints: Enabled  .... disabled now. Thanks for your help

...what? what is shown in that screenshot is not inlay hints. cc @trouselife. why did you accept an answer that is totally wrong?
